# Spring Batch simple admin interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am looking for a simple replacement for [Spring Batch Admin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/trunk/%22Spring%20Batch%20Admin%22). I don't have time to research frameworks like [Apache Kafka](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/) in order to view, start and stop my jobs in a graphical user interface.

Comment: As stated on the Spring Batch Admin website: it's replacement is Spring Cloud Data Flow.

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/codecentric/spring-batch-admin-spring-boot ?

Comment: Have you tried Lenses for Apache Kafka ? It should only take a few moments to start-up and provides an excellent user interface for viewing data, starting and stopping, scaling etc your jobs
 
http://landoop.com/docs/lenses/developers